# gitlab-ci is not calling image tag called at the beginning

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have an gitlab-ci.yml with the following

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  TASK_DEFINTION_NAME:  first-run-task-definition
  CLUSTER_NAME: lellevo-web-cluster
  SERVICE_NAME: lellevo-web-cont-service

before_script:
  - chmod +x setup_env.sh
  - ./setup_env.sh
  - docker info
  - apk add --no-cache curl jq python py-pip
  - pip install awscli
  - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region "${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}")
  - IMAGE_TAG="$(echo $CI_COMMIT_SHA | head -c 8)"
```

And I get it is like the docker image it is not being called because I get the following

[image]

I get the same with apk

I added a

```
 - ls -al /usr/bin
```

No apk

And I found apt or apt-cache binaries and the docker image is based on alpine.  I tried running apt and it runs.
I added my own image jdcb/docker-aws-cli so I have docker and aws images and get problems with docker and aws.
I added some random image like
`image: dockerxxxxxxxxxxx:latest` and I get no error.  I don`t know what I am doing wrong I am pretty sure at first it did work I had other errors.

Comment: Does it work if you add the TLS-specific `variables` as show [here](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2019/07/31/docker-in-docker-with-docker-19-dot-03/)?

Comment: Thanks, it wasnt tls but using image: docker:19.03.0 and docker:19.03.0-dind as service helped